# How to do Interpolation in Pyomo.DAE

Tags: pyomo

I have some time steps values that I already defined in my data but I don't wanna make use of it. I instead want to make use of the **discretized points** from the `ContinuousSet` as my new time span.

I tried interpolating my data after applying the discretization but after running it, I noticed three things:

1. my constraints were more than my variables.
2. when I print my parameters, it shows the interpolated time points but no value is attached to those time points.
3. I also noticed the discretization is adding additional points than what I specified (I don't think this is right). I have 97 rows in my data but when I print my parameters, it shows 98.

I can't really figure out where the error is coming from.

Below is my code and a picture of the error:

```
df = pd.read_csv('digester_influent_PyADM13.csv')
model = m = ConcreteModel()

m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1))

m.Ssu_in = Param(m.t, mutable=True)
m.Saa_in = Param(m.t, mutable=True)
m.Sfa_in = Param(m.t, mutable=True)
m.Q = Param(m.t, mutable=True)
m.V_liq = Param(initialize=3400, within=PositiveReals)

discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
discretizer.apply_to(m,nfe=(96*1+1),wrt=m.t,scheme='BACKWARD')

# Interpolate the data
timepoints = list(ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1)))
data_timepoints = df['time'].tolist()
data_profiles1 = df['S_su'].tolist()
data_profiles2 = df['S_aa'].tolist()
data_profiles3 = df['S_fa'].tolist()
data_profiles4 = df['Q'].tolist()

interp_Ssu_values = np.interp(timepoints, data_timepoints, data_profiles1)
interp_Saa_values = np.interp(timepoints, data_timepoints, data_profiles2)
interp_Sfa_values = np.interp(timepoints, data_timepoints, data_profiles3)
interp_Q_values = np.interp(timepoints, data_timepoints, data_profiles4)

for i,t in enumerate(timepoints):
    m.Ssu_in[t] = interp_Ssu_values[i]
    m.Saa_in[t] = interp_Saa_values[i]
    m.Sfa_in[t] = interp_Sfa_values[i]
    m.Q[t] = interp_Q_values[i]

# Variables
m.S_su = Var(m.t, initialize=0.012394, domain=PositiveReals, bounds=(0.001,1))               
m.S_aa = Var(m.t, initialize=0.0055432, domain=PositiveReals, bounds=(0,0.1))                  
m.S_fa = Var(m.t, initialize=0.10741, domain=PositiveReals, bounds=(0.001,2)) 
m.dS_su_dt = DerivativeVar(m.S_su, wrt=m.t)
m.dS_aa_dt = DerivativeVar(m.S_aa, wrt=m.t)
m.dS_fa_dt = DerivativeVar(m.S_fa, wrt=m.t)

# Initial Values
m.S_su[0].fix(0.012394)
m.S_aa[0].fix(0.0055432)
m.S_fa[0].fix(0.10741)

# Differential equations
def S_su_out_bal(m,t):
    return m.dS_su_dt[t] == (m.Q[t]/m.V_liq) * (m.Ssu_in[t] - m.S_su[t]) + 0.000662979
m.Ssu_outcon = Constraint(m.t, rule=S_su_out_bal)

def S_aa_out_bal(m,t):
    return m.dS_aa_dt[t] == (m.Q[t]/m.V_liq) * (m.Saa_in[t] - m.S_aa[t]) - 0.00202160
m.Saa_outcon = Constraint(m.t, rule=S_aa_out_bal)

def S_fa_out_bal(m,t):
    return m.dS_fa_dt[t] == (m.Q[t]/m.V_liq) * (m.Sfa_in[t] - m.S_fa[t]) + 0.005667982
m.Sfa_outcon = Constraint(m.t, rule=S_fa_out_bal)

# Check to see if the number of Constraints equals the number of variables
from pyomo.util.model_size import build_model_size_report
report = build_model_size_report(m)
print('Num constraints: ', report.activated.constraints)
print('Num variables: ', report.activated.variables)
```

Output:

```
Num constraints:  294
Num variables:  585
```

Display Q values:

```
m.Q.display()
```

Ouput:

```
Q : Size=98, Index=t, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=True
    Key      : Value
           0 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.010309 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.020619 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.030928 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.041237 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.051546 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.061856 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.072165 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.082474 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.092784 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.103093 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.113402 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.123711 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.134021 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
     0.14433 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.154639 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.164948 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
    0.175258 : <class 'pyomo.core.base.param.Param.NoValue'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the issues I see:

1. This line: `timepoints = list(ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1)))` is creating a new ContinuousSet, I think you want this instead: `timepoints = list(m.t)`
2. You need to declare all of the `Var` and `DerivativeVar` components **before** applying the discretization transformation.

Comment: Thank you @BethanyNicholson! It worked. However, It still adds an additional point to my data.

I specified `nfe` = 97. It is returning 98. I explicitly want 97 and don't want it to add any additional point.

Comment: `nfe` stands for "number of finite elements". 1 finite element consists of 2 points, 2 finite elements is 3 points, and so on. So if you want 97 points then you should specify `nfe=96`